# Linkify in EditText to Detect Hashtags

Tags: android, android-edittext, hashtag, linkify

I am using `Linkify` to detect hashtags in a `TextView` and it's working fine but I want to implement it inside an `EditText` control.

This is the way that I use `Linkify` in `TextView`:

```
Pattern tagMatcher = Pattern.compile(("#([ء-يA-Za-z0-9_-]+)"));
String newActivityURL = "content://com.hashtag.jojo/";

Pattern urlPattern = Patterns.WEB_URL;

TransformFilter transformFilter = new TransformFilter() {
    // skip the first character to filter out '@'
    public String transformUrl(final Matcher match, String url) {
        return match.group(0);
    }
};
Linkify.addLinks(TextView, Linkify.ALL);
Linkify.addLinks(TextView, tagMatcher,newActivityURL, null,transformFilter);
```

How do I apply this to an `EditText`?

Comment: and what problem do you have?

Comment: The Linkify dose not accept an EditText it Just for TextView

Comment: as Gary111 said EditText  is a TextView you can use it anywhere TextView can be used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do what you do with EditText instead of TextView, because EditText extends from TextView. It must be work fine.

Little example:

```
EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
editText1.setText("http://http://www.dzone.com/");
Linkify.addLinks(editText1 , Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

If you want check it in real-time just do something like that:

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        Linkify.addLinks(editText1 , Linkify.WEB_URLS);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```

**updated**

```
final TransformFilter filter = new TransformFilter() {
    public final String transformUrl(final Matcher match, String url) {
        return match.group();
    }
};

final Pattern hashtagPattern = Pattern.compile("#([ء-يA-Za-z0-9_-]+)");
final String hashtagScheme = "content://com.hashtag.jojo/";

final Pattern urlPattern = Patterns.WEB_URL;

editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        System.out.println(count);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        Linkify.addLinks(s, hashtagPattern, hashtagScheme, null, filter);
        Linkify.addLinks(s, urlPattern, null, null, filter);
    }
});
```

Comment: i want the link to apeer while Writing inside EditText

Comment: see my updated code with TextWatcher it works while typing/writing

Comment: this works for the links but not working for hashtag 
and its gives 05-24 java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: One problem is the the afterTextChanged method will get called again if the tags modify the content, leaving you in an infinite loop.

Comment: @BrillPappin, I just curiosity, could you post an example code in gist or other code sharing system.

Comment: @Gary111 doesn't that code above do that for you? I've been messing with it all day and keep running into that issue.
if the links modify the content in the s var, the afterTextChanged method will get called again.